# How come the genus of algebraic curve can be any natural number?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> One the one hand, any topological surface has a complex structure, so for any natural number $g$, there exists a complex curve with genus $g$. On the other hand, we have a Chow's theorem, which says that any complex analytic variety is algebraic. This means that there exists a non-singular algebraic curve with genus $g$. But algebraic curves have a well-defined degree $d$ which connect to the notion of genus using the formula $g=(d-1)(d-2)/2$. This suggests that $g$ cannot be any natural number.

Obviously this argument has a flaw, but where?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The formula you gives concerns *plane algebraic curves*, but, in general a curve cannot embed in $\bf CP^2$ but in $\bf CP^3$.

Comment: Is there a formula for the genus of a degree $d$ curve in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^3$ ?

Comment: @Mihail one way to produce a curve of any genus in $\Bbb P^3$ is as a divisor on $\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1\subset \Bbb P^3$: a divisor of type $(a,b)$ on this surface has genus $(a-1)(b-1)$ by adjunction.

Comment: @Mihail, there exists smooth rational (= genus 0) curves of any degree in $CP^3$.